# How can I set a condition on CVI to trigger once per moving?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I have the next code that calculates CVI and alerts me if is rising or falling.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="CVI", shorttitle="CVi")
length=input(3)
vc=ta.sma(hl2, length)
useModifiedFormula=input.bool(false)
os1=input(-0.51, title="Oversold 1")
ob1=input(0.43, title="Overbought 1")

denom = (useModifiedFormula == true) ? (ta.atr(length) * math.sqrt(length)) : ta.atr(length)
cvi = (close-vc) / denom
    
isRising = ta.rising(cvi,1)
isFalling = ta.falling(cvi,1)
      
//alerts
alertcondition(isRising, title = "Long", message="Long")    
alertcondition(isFalling, title = "Short", message="Short")
```

How can I set the condition to trigger once per moving, and not every time is rising or falling? (is rising? ok, keep rising, notify me only when is falling and vice versa)

Thanks,
Raul

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem. I have to add this condition for direction

```
direction = 0
direction := isRising ? 1 : isFalling ? -1 : nz(direction[1])
change_direction= ta.change(direction,1)
```

and then to add change_direction to alertcondition()